# Accurately Timing Sounds In-Browser For A Metronome

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I want to create a virtual metronome and play a metronome sound with each step.  Usual methods such as `setTimeout()`/`setInterval()` are not accurate enough.  How can I make it work without delay or dropping beats?

Comment: The answer is to use the `AudioBufferSourceNode` and call `.start()` with the `when` parameter to indicate exactly at which timestamp the metronome sound should start.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode/start  That will guarantee audio accuracy.  If you also wanted to trigger some other code when this happens, that isn't possible.  You would have to use other methods, like intervals, to do other things once the time has passed.  You can use `audioContext.currentTime` to determine the current timestamp.

Comment: So there is no way to trigger some code after `AudioBufferSourceNode.start();`?

Comment: Not based on time, no.  And even if you could, it wouldn't be helpful to you because its timing could be off.  So, if you need to schedule audio, you need to do it early by calling `.start()` with a timestamp.  If you want to display things on the screen, you can use `requestAnimationFrame` but note that this will be throttled or outright paused if the tab loses focus.

Comment: So Mr. Brad what do you suggest for triggering some codes in an exact time (the best way at all)?

Comment: You can't.  You need to find another way.  Post a question with specifically what you're trying to do.

Comment: I updated the answer. Hope this leads you in the right direction.

Comment: Note that a reliable BPM counter usually doesn't tick at "that many beats per minute", since you'd only be able to trigger quarter/quaver notes. Instead you want want to look at the actual current time by running a timer at the highest possible rate, e.g. by using `requestAnimationFrame` and running a check to see whether to trigger a next division unit or not based on a knowledge of what _clock time_ your start happened on and the current time.

Comment: Related: [HTML5/jQuery metronome - performance problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211567/html5-jquery-metronome-performance-problems/68249713#68249713) and [making a Javascript metronome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75632384/making-a-javascript-metronome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [function that beeps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23395136/1487756) every 500ms.

```js
function beep() {
    var snd = new Audio("data:audio/wav;base64,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");  
    snd.play();
}

setInterval(beep, 500)
```

That's however not very precise. The callback may be fired late (depending on a lot, this can range from a few ms to over 1000ms). To get around this you can use [`AudioContext`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext). We'll use a simple `Oscillator` for the Metronomes sound.

You could either schedule multiple notes at once or use `setInterval` to run a function that schedules the next note that should be played.

```js
function noteDurationToMs (bpm, dur, type) {
    return 60000 * 4 * dur * type / bpm
}

function scheduleNote(ac, time, dur) {
    var osc = ac.createOscillator();
    osc.connect( ac.destination );
    osc.start(time);
    osc.stop(time + dur);
}

const ac = new AudioContext();
let lastNote= ac.currentTime;
const step = noteDurationToMs(120, 1 / 4, 1) / 1000;
const lookAhead = step / 2;

let id, timer = ()=> {
  const diff = ac.currentTime - lastNote;
  if (diff >= lookAhead) {
   const nextNote = lastNote + step;
   scheduleNote(ac, nextNote, 0.025)
   lastNote = nextNote;
  }
}
a.addEventListener('click', () => {
    ac.resume();
    id = setInterval(timer, 15)
})
b.addEventListener('click', () => clearInterval(id))
```

```html
<button id="a">Start</button>
<button id="b">Stop</button>
```

<del>**Note: for some reason `AudioContext` doesn't seem to be working in Stack Snippets.**</del> Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xenj0o1k/1/) for the first code snippet. Here is [one](https://jsfiddle.net/zL60wm7f/) for the second snippet.

```js
function noteDurationToMs (bpm, dur, type) {
    return 60000 * 4 * dur * type / bpm
}

function scheduleNote(ac, time, dur) {
    var osc = ac.createOscillator();
    osc.connect( ac.destination );
    
    
    osc.start(time);
    osc.stop(time + dur);
}

const ac = new AudioContext();
let to, lastNote = 0;

const Metronome = () => {
  const [bpm, setBpm] = React.useState(100);
  const [dur, setDur] = React.useState(1);  
  const [type, setType] = React.useState(1);
    const [run, setRun] = React.useState(false);    
  
  const handleChangeBPM = (e) => {
    setBpm(e.target.value)
  }
  
  const handleChangeDur = (e) => {
    setDur(e.target.value)
  }
  
  const handleChangeType = (e) => {
    setType(e.target.value)
  }
  
  const step = noteDurationToMs(bpm, dur, type) / 1000;
    const lookAhead = step / 2;
  
  const timer = () => {
    const diff = ac.currentTime - lastNote;
    if (diff >= lookAhead) {
     const nextNote = lastNote + step;
     scheduleNote(ac, nextNote, 0.025)
     lastNote = nextNote;
    }
  }
  
  const start = () => {
    ac.resume()
    setRun(true);
  }
  
  const stop = () => {
    clearInterval(to);
    setRun(false);
  }
  
  const toggle = () => {
    run?stop():start();
  }

    React.useEffect(() => {
    if (run) {
        clearInterval(to);
      to = setInterval(timer, step / 4);
    }
  });
  
    return <div>
    <label for="bpm">BPM:</label>

    
      <input id="bpm" type="number" onChange={handleChangeBPM} value={bpm} />
    
    <label for="dur">Duration:</label>
    
    <select id="dur" onChange={handleChangeDur} value={dur}>
      <option value={1}>Whole</option>
      <option value={1 / 2}>Half</option>
      <option value={1 / 4}>Quarter</option>
      <option value={1 / 8}>Eigth </option>
      <option value={1 / 16}>Sixteenth</option>
      <option value={1 / 32}>Thirtysecond</option>
    </select>
    
    <label for="typ">Type:</label>
    <select id="typ" onChange={handleChangeType} value={type}>
      <option value={1}>Regular</option>
      <option value={3 / 2}>Dotted</option>
      <option value={2 / 3}>Triplet</option>
    </select>
    <button onClick={toggle}>{!run?'Start':'Stop'}</button>
    <br />
    <label for="ms">MS:</label>
    <output id="ms">{noteDurationToMs(bpm, dur, type)}</output>
    </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<Metronome />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

---

*To include your own edit:*
You are also able to use [`AudioBufferSourceNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode/start) and call `.start()`, with the `when` parameter to play an audio exactly at time but you would not be able to run a function with it.

`AudioBufferSourceNode.start([when]);`

Comment: Not bad, but there is a little bit of delay between beep sounds. Is there any better way?

Comment: @AliAhmadi There is an delay, but it should only be around 1-2ms. I updated the answer. I thought you can use `requestAnimationFrame` to increase precision, but it seems it's even worse than `setTimeout`. I don't think there is anything you can do to improve that.

Comment: can we remove around 1-2ms delay?

Comment: How I can use prescheduled audio events? like `https://metronomes.glitch.me/`

Comment: @AliAhmadi Yes, that's possible audio scheduling. But that's out of the scope of this question. You might want to read this article [https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/scheduling/](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/scheduling/). The code for their metronome demo using scheduling can be [found here](https://github.com/cwilso/metronome/)

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: When I run this code the time between sounds is 599ms - 617ms.

Comment: You know a better way?

Comment: This answer is wrong.  To get accurate timing, you *must* use the Web Audio API.  `requestAnimationFrame()` is not appropriate, at all.  Even if it were fast enough, it's tied to the visual context... not the audio.

Comment: @Brad Yes. I'll update it when I find some time.

Comment: @Brad Updated the answer using `AudioContext`